# How Binding Converter to a control's property can access other properties of the control

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, binding, ivalueconverter

I am trying to bind a value "MaxLines" to the TextBlock's Height property in WP7 app. There is a converter to the binding which is supposed to multiple the LineHeight with the MaxLines and return the expected height. What I am trying to say is I want to control the number of lines being shown in the TextBlock. How will I be able to access the TextBlock's LineHeight property from the converter.

To make this generic I did not want maintain the LineHeights separately or access them from viewModel

Answer (score 2):

Check out this article, [Silverlight data binding and value converters](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx), where he explains how to Databind in Silverlight. In the example he uses a ValueConverter with parametervalue.

I think that is what you need, just bind your LineHeight to the parameter. (You can use Blend for that)

Comment: Passing the object reference or the line height through ConverterParameter is not working. The Application is crashing.

Comment: An invalidOperationException at MS.Internal.XamlManagedRuntimeRPInvokes.TryApplyMarkupExtensionValue(Object target, XamlPropertyToken propertyToken, Object value)

Comment: No error when ConverterParameter is removed. I thought that .net compact framework does not allow ConverterParameter. Or may be only constants are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ConverterParameter:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Height="{Binding ConverterParameter=Height, ElementName=MyTextBlock, Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}}" Text="{Binding SomeLongText}" />
```

or pass the whole textblock:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Height="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ImageFileConverter}, ElementName=DropdownImage}" Text="{Binding SomeLongText}" />
```

Then inside the controller:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var image = value as TextBlock;
            /*do your magic here*/
}
```

Comment: Passing the object reference or the line height through ConverterParameter is not working. The Application is crashing.

Comment: Height="{Binding LineOneHeight, Converter={StaticResource hConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding ElementName=dTextblock}}" This is how I am binding.

Comment: Try this: Height="{Binding Converter={StaticResource hConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding LineOneHeight,ElementName=dTextblock}}"